# Is it true in general that a filter is given by the intersection of the ultrafilters refining it?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory, filters

In set theory it holds that any *filter* is the intersection of all the *ultrafilters* refining it. By the way the definition of filter can be given in a more general context, that is as a particular subset of a partially ordered set. The set-case is then a particular example, taking as poset the powerset and as order relation the inclusion. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(mathematics). I was wondering if the above property is still valid in such a general situation, or at least for the case of a *principal filter*. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For general posets we have to review the usual definition of ultrafilter (a filter where for every set either the set or its complement is in the filter; outside the set-setup we don't have the notion of complement), e.g. say that it is a maximal proper filter (i.e. any larger filter is the whole poset). However, with the poset $(\{1,2,3,4\},\le)$, we have only one maximal proper filter $U=\{2,3,4\}$, hence the filter $F=\{3,4\}$ is not the intersection of its containing ultrafilters.